# Make all adobe -labels to start with word "adobe"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

This question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7798/illustrator-cs6-where-did-the-debug-panel-go-computing-area-of-irregular-shape) is bad in labeling. CS6 should be redirected to `adobe-cs6` and `illustrator` should be redirected to `adobe-illustrator`. We need a stop to this bias, use consistent labels. It will be easier then for people to find adobe -material fast if they really want to, creating all the time new words for all kind of marketing gimmicks such as illustartor etc is nonsense, prepend them with word `adobe` to get this issue clearer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed.  All questions marked "illustrator" were specific to Adobe Illustrator.

The tags are now merged.